# Having the class and constructor different access modifiers

Tags: c#

When would you want to declare a class `internal` but its constructor `public`? When I create a class, its access modifier is almost always the same as the constructor.

```
internal class A
{
   public A() 
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780801/whats-the-difference-between-a-public-constructor-in-an-internal-class-and-an-i